# Moving an object ArrayList to another class

Tags: java, object, arraylist

My program has two classes, one that scans a file called `Flights.csv` and uses the information to construct an arraylist of a Flight object, and another class that scan a file called `Airports.csv` and creates an arraylist of Airport objects from this. I want to move the arraylist of my flight object into my Airport class so I can compare what city the Flights start from with the city of the Airport and print out a list of what flights depart from what airports.

Here's the constructor for the Airport class

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.StringTokenizer;
public class Airport{
  String name;
  double latitude;
  double longitude;
  int conTime;
  String city;
  static ArrayList<Airport> Airports = new ArrayList<Airport>();
 public Airport(String nmst, double lat, double lon, int del, String cst) {
  name = nmst;
  latitude = lat;
  longitude = lon;
  conTime = del;
  city = cst;
  Airports.add(this);
  }
```

And here's the Flight Class constructor

```
public class Flight {
 String flightNum;
 String cityFrom;
 String cityTo;
 String departTime;
 String arriveTime;
 String price;
 String seats;
 String brand;
 static ArrayList<Flight> Flights = new ArrayList<Flight>();
 public Flight(String flights,  String cityF, String cityT, String departT, String arriveT, 
 String    cost, String space, String name) {

flightNum = flights;
price = cost; 
cityFrom = cityF;
cityTo = cityT;
departTime = departT;
arriveTime = arriveT;
seats  = space;
brand = name;
Flights.add(this);
}
```

How do you get an arraylist like this into another class?

Comment: Create a `getter()` method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why are you creating an ArrayList of Airport in class Airport and creating an ArrayList of Flight in class Flight?

If you want Airport to be able to see a full list of Flights, you can add an ArrayList of Flight into class Airport.

```
class Airport
{
    //other variables
    ArrayList<Flight> flightList;
}
```

You can either add the list of Flights into an Airport object via:

1. The Airport constructor **OR**
2. The Airport setter (setFlights(ArrayList flightList)) **OR**
3. A method in Airport which adds new flights

To be able to **retrieve** the list of flights from your Airport object, you need a **getter** in your Class Airport:

```
public ArrayList<Flight> getFlights()
{
    return flightList;
}
```

---

**A complete example:**

Adding through **1. The Airport constructor**

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    ArrayList<Flight> flightList = new ArrayList<Flight>();
    flightList.add(new Flight(...)); //The ... within the braces depends on your Flight constructor
    flightList.add(new Flight(...)); //The ... within the braces depends on your Flight constructor
    flightList.add(new Flight(...)); //The ... within the braces depends on your Flight constructor

    Airport airport = new Airport(flightList); //Now airport has a list of flights    
}
```

Adding through **2. The Airport setter methods (Mutators)**

```
//Within your Airport class
public void setFlight(ArrayList<Flight> flightList)
{
    this.flightList = flightList;
}
```

Adding through **3. A method in Airport which adds new flights**

If you do not want to get flights through the constructor, and there is a chance that you may want to **add new flights** one by one, you can create another `addFlight(Flight newFlight)` method:

```
public void addFlight(Flight newFlight)
{
    flightList.add(newFlight);
}
```

---

In case you are wondering the use of **getter and setter**. We are using it because your flightList will be `private`. In order to access a `private` member, we need "help" from a `public` method. These methods which give us access to `private` members are known as **getter/setter**, or better knows as **accessor/mutator**.

Comment: please if you can add getter and setter concept to your answer

Comment: @KickButtowski you mean you want me to explain the getter & setter?

Comment: yes so you can have more informative answer I have already +1 u

Comment: @KickButtowski Thanks, I am adding more things to my reply..

Comment: Sorry, I figured it out, it was just Flight.Flights, I didn't know you could do that.

Comment: @MaximusDolphin If my answer is useful to you, you may consider accepting my answer ;)